# Apache Superset Dashboard Filter with URL parameter

Tags: apache-superset

Is there a way to pass url parameters to filter slice? somewhat like
http://localhost:8080/superset/dashboard/15/?tableColumnName=value

I have a filter slice on tableColumnName

Answer (score 3):

preselect_filters like below works:

preselect_filters={"76":{"tableColumnName":["value1"]}}

Comment: A similar discussion is found here. https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/4985

Comment: this preselect_filters where we have to insert?

Comment: @Manisha It should be pass as url params like this ````http://{url}:8088/superset/dashboard/{dashboard_id}/?preselect_filters={{"chart_id"}:{{"column_to_be_filtered"}: {"value_to_be_filtered"}}}````