# Apache Superset: how to customize native filters in an URL?

Tags: url, dashboard, apache-superset

I wish to create customized URL opening a superset dashboard with filters customized for different users.
Typically, I have a column 'city' and I want to have several URLs: 1 for user interested by the city of Austin, other for user interested by New York, etc...
I've created a Native Filter in the dashboard. But I fail to create the specific URL.

I tried to apply the answers provided here ([URL filter parameters in Apache Superset dashboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63950646/url-filter-parameters-in-apache-superset-dashboards) and https://www.blef.fr/superset-filters-in-url/ ) but everytime I tried the URl, it opens the native one without changing the filters.

**Superset version:** 2.0.0

**Examples:**
The URL of my dashboard is localhost:8088/superset/dashboard/55/?native_filters_key=QhV7Icb0SBVQJGUqMqA78qk3R76TQd76-Bxv3x_4KxNVIF0Y6IXTlnqIrXxHtpRu

Applying https://www.blef.fr/superset-filters-in-url/, I enter in my browser this new URL:
localhost:8088/superset/dashboard/55/?native_filters=(NATIVE_FILTER-PQwd_qYqN-:(__cache:(label:'Austin',validateStatus:!f,validateMessage:!f,value:!('Austin')),
extraFormData:(filters:!((col:'city',op:IN,val:!('Austin')))),
filterState:(label:'Austin',validateStatus:!f,validateMessage:!f,value:!('Austin')),id:NATIVE_FILTER-PQwd_qYqN-,ownState:()))

But it opens only localhost:8088/superset/dashboard/55/?native_filters_key=QhV7Icb0SBVQJGUqMqA78qk3R76TQd76-Bxv3x_4KxNVIF0Y6IXTlnqIrXxHtpRu

I checked the syntax but I didn't find my mistake... Any Idea?

Comment: Check this tutorial for URL parameter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5v0keE_RlSA&ab_channel=PresetUser%27sCorner

Answer (score 0):

You must also add feature flags in your superset_config.py file

```
FEATURE_FLAGS = {"DASHBOARD_FILTERS_EXPERIMENTAL": True, "DASHBOARD_NATIVE_FILTERS_SET": True, "DASHBOARD_NATIVE_FILTERS": True, "DASHBOARD_CROSS_FILTERS": True, "ENABLE_TEMPLATE_PROCESSING": True}
```